# Cursor for loop creating duplicate entries for nested XQUERY

Tags: oracle, plsql, xml-parsing, xquery, xmltable

I have created a procedure which is parsing xml data into multiple tables. I am catching exception for primary key constraint, and if there is a duplicate found in result, it will be inserted into a table named as DUPLICATE.
Now when i use the cursor it tends to iterate more than the required number of times i.e. 1. 
**Procedure**

```
DECLARE
PER_ID varchar2(20);
    NAME varchar2(20);
SECTIONS_ID varchar2(20);
SECTIONS_NAME varchar2(20);
    var1 number;
    exception_var number;
CURSOR C1 IS
    select d.department_id
       , d.department_name
       , s.sections_id
      , s.sections_name
   from xml_unit_download t
     , xmltable(
         '/ROWSET/DATA'
         passing t.xml_file
         columns
           DEPARTMENT_ID   varchar2(20) path 'DEPARTMENT/DEPARTMENT_ID'
         , DEPARTMENT_NAME varchar2(30) path 'DEPARTMENT/DEPARTMENT_NAME'
         , SECTIONS        xmltype      path 'SECTIONS'
       ) d
     , xmltable(
         '/SECTIONS'
         passing d.sections
         columns
           SECTIONS_ID     varchar2(20) path 'SECTIONS_ID'
        , SECTIONS_NAME   varchar2(30) path 'SECTIONS_NAME'
      ) s
 where
  t.Status = 4;
  BEGIN

  FOR R_C1 IN C1 LOOP
      BEGIN
      insert into DEPARTMENT(id, name) values(R_C1.PER_ID, R_C1.name);
      insert into SECTIONS(id, name) values(R_C1.SECTIONS_ID, R_C1.SECTIONS_NAME);
      var1:= var1+1;
       dbms_output.put_line('Insert=' || var1);
      commit;
           --dbms_output.put_line('Duplicate='||var);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
         dbms_output.put_line('Duplicate=');
         insert into duplicate(id, name)values(R_C1.id, R_C1_name);
      END;
      END LOOP;
  END;
```

How am i going to handle this situation? I have tried using INSERT ALL also but it does not seem to work. Here is my try of INSERT ALL procedure

```
DECLARE
PER_ID varchar2(20);
    NAME varchar2(200);
    var1 number;
    exception_var number;

  BEGIN

      insert all
      into SECTIONS (id) values(department_id)

      --into sect (id, name) values(s.SECTIONS_ID, s.SECTIONS_NAME )
   select d.department_id
       , d.department_name
       , s.sections_id
      , s.sections_name
   from xml_unit_download t
     , xmltable(
         '/ROWSET/DATA'
         passing t.xml_file
         columns
           "DEPARTMENT_ID"   varchar2(20) path 'DEPARTMENT/DEPARTMENT_ID'
         , "DEPARTMENT_NAME" varchar2(30) path 'DEPARTMENT/DEPARTMENT_NAME'
         , "SECTIONS"        xmltype      path 'SECTIONS'
       ) d
     , xmltable(
         '/SECTIONS'
         passing d.sections
         columns
           "SECTIONS_ID"     varchar2(20) path 'SECTIONS_ID'
        , "SECTIONS_NAME"   varchar2(30) path 'SECTIONS_NAME'
      ) s
 where
  t.Status = 4;
  dbms_output.put_line('Insert=' || var1);
      var1:= var1+1;
       dbms_output.put_line('Insert=' || var1);
      commit;
           --dbms_output.put_line('Duplicate='||var);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
         --insert into
         dbms_output.put_line('Duplicate=');
  END;
```

The XML which is being queried contains data of DEPARTMENT and its SECTIONS. DEPARTMENT has one to many relationship with SECTIONS i.e. a DEPARTMENT can have one or multiple SECTIONS and there may be instances where DEPARTMENT will not have any SECTIONS.

Structure of XML is such that  tag identifies a DEPARTMENT and set of its corresponding SECTIONS.
**XML**

```
<ROWSET> 
<DATA>
 <DEPARTMENT>
  <DEPARTMENT_ID>DEP1</DEPARTMENT_ID>
  <DEPARTMENT_NAME>myDEPARTMENT1</DEPARTMENT_NAME>
 </DEPARTMENT>
 <SECTIONS>
  <SECTIONS_ID>6390135666643567</SECTIONS_ID>
  <SECTIONS_NAME>mySection1</SECTIONS_NAME>
  </SECTIONS>
   <SECTIONS>
  <SECTIONS_ID>6390135666643567</SECTIONS_ID>
  <SECTIONS_NAME>mySection2</SECTIONS_NAME>
  </SECTIONS>
 </DATA>
 <DATA>
 <DEPARTMENT>
  <DEPARTMENT_ID>DEP2</DEPARTMENT_ID>
  <DEPARTMENT_NAME>myDEPARTMENT2</DEPARTMENT_NAME>
 </DEPARTMENT>
 <SECTIONS>
  <SECTIONS_ID>63902</SECTIONS_ID>
  <SECTIONS_NAME>mySection1</SECTIONS_NAME>
  </SECTIONS>
 </DATA>
<DATA>
 <DEPARTMENT>
  <DEPARTMENT_ID>DEP3</DEPARTMENT_ID>
  <DEPARTMENT_NAME>myDEPARTMENT3</DEPARTMENT_NAME>
 </DEPARTMENT>
</DATA>
</ROWSET>
```

Comment: If you've got two sections in a department, your query will return two rows, with the same department info and different section info (as you can see running the query on its own). So a duplicate department is 'valid', and you can't distinguish between two sections for one department, and two identical departments with one section each, if that's what you're trying to do. Either way, because your duplicate dept gets the exception, the second section is never inserted. You could just put the exception handler around the first insert, but this doesn't seem like the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can have multiple sections in each department, you'll expect duplicates. You might be able to get what you want just by moving where you catch the exception, so it will still do the insert into `sections`:

```
  FOR R_C1 IN C1 LOOP
      BEGIN
         insert into DEPARTMENT(id, name)
            values(R_C1.department_id, R_C1.department_name);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
         dbms_output.put_line('Duplicate=');
         insert into duplicate(id, name)
            values(R_C1.department_id, R_C1.department_name);
      END;
      insert into SECTIONS(id, name)
         values(R_C1.SECTIONS_ID, R_C1.SECTIONS_NAME);
      var1:= var1+1;
      dbms_output.put_line('Insert=' || var1);
   END LOOP;
```

You could also use tracker variables (if you see a record with the same `department_id` as the previous one you saw, don't attempt to insert a `department` record, just do the `sections` insert), or you could use nested loops:

```
declare
   cursor dept_cur is
      select d.department_id
         , d.department_name
         , d.sections
      from xml_unit_download t
         , xmltable(
            '/ROWSET/DATA'
            passing t.xml_file
            columns
              "DEPARTMENT_ID"   varchar2(20) path 'DEPARTMENT/DEPARTMENT_ID'
            , "DEPARTMENT_NAME" varchar2(30) path 'DEPARTMENT/DEPARTMENT_NAME'
            , "SECTIONS"        xmltype      path 'SECTIONS'
         ) d
      where
         t.Status = 4;

   cursor sect_cur(sections xmltype) is
      select s.sections_id
         , s.sections_name
      from xmltable(
            '/SECTIONS'
            passing sections
            columns
              "SECTIONS_ID"     varchar2(20) path 'SECTIONS_ID'
           , "SECTIONS_NAME"   varchar2(30) path 'SECTIONS_NAME'
         ) s;
begin
   for dept in dept_cur loop
      insert into department(id, name)
         values (dept.department_id, dept.department_name);
      for sect in sect_cur(dept.sections) loop
         insert into sections(id, name, department_id)
            values (sect.sections_id, sect.sections_name, dept.department_id);
      end loop;
   end loop;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

This uses one loop to get the department info (which won't have duplicates) plus the XMLTYPE sections, and then passes the section to the second cursor to expand.

```
select * from department;

ID                             NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
DEP1                           myDEPARTMENT1
DEP2                           myDEPARTMENT2
DEP3                           myDEPARTMENT3

select * from sections;

ID                             NAME                           DEPARTMENT_ID
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
6390135666643567               mySection1                     DEP1
6390135666643567               mySection2                     DEP1
63902                          mySection1                     DEP2
```

You don't have to use PL/SQL, you could just do two inserts:

```
insert into department(id, name)
select d.department_id
   , d.department_name
from xml_unit_download t
   , xmltable(
      '/ROWSET/DATA'
      passing t.xml_file
      columns
        "DEPARTMENT_ID"   varchar2(20) path 'DEPARTMENT/DEPARTMENT_ID'
      , "DEPARTMENT_NAME" varchar2(30) path 'DEPARTMENT/DEPARTMENT_NAME'
   ) d
where
   t.Status = 4;
```

... and:

```
insert into sections(id, name, department_id)
select s.sections_id
   , s.sections_name
   , d.department_id
from xml_unit_download t
   , xmltable(
      '/ROWSET/DATA'
      passing t.xml_file
      columns 
        "DEPARTMENT_ID"   varchar2(20) path 'DEPARTMENT/DEPARTMENT_ID'
      , "DEPARTMENT_NAME" varchar2(30) path 'DEPARTMENT/DEPARTMENT_NAME'
      , "SECTIONS"        xmltype      path 'SECTIONS'
   ) d
   , xmltable(
      '/SECTIONS'
      passing d.sections
      columns 
        "SECTIONS_ID"     varchar2(20) path 'SECTIONS_ID'
     , "SECTIONS_NAME"   varchar2(30) path 'SECTIONS_NAME'
   ) s
where
   t.Status = 4;
```

... which put the same data in the tables as the PL/SQL block does.

In both I've assumed you want a column linking the two tables, but perhaps they aren't uniquely linked and you want separate `section` and `department_section` tables, which could easily be generated in the same way.

Also note that both approaches create a `department` record for `DEP3`, which your original wouldn't do, unless you used the outer joins from a previous answer; and then you'd have to notice there was no section info and not attempt the second insert.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a basic cardinality issue - if you have more than one section in a department, then you're going to get more than one row for each department in the results and therefore you'll see duplicate department information because of the program code rather than the input data.

Instead of trying to do this in one query, why not break it up into two cursor/for loops?

Something like this:

```
BEGIN

  <<department_loop>>
  FOR r_department IN (
    SELECT 
      d.department_id
    , d.department_name
    , d.sections
    FROM xml_unit_download t
   , XMLTABLE(
     '/ROWSET/DATA'
     PASSING t.xml_file
     COLUMNS
       department_id   VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'DEPARTMENT/DEPARTMENT_ID'
     , department_name VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'DEPARTMENT/DEPARTMENT_NAME'
     , sections        XMLTYPE      path 'SECTIONS'
    ) d
    WHERE t.status = 4
  )
  LOOP

    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO departments (id, name)
      VALUES (r_department.department_id, r_department.department_name);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        INSERT INTO department_duplicates (id, name)
        VALUES (r_department.department_id, r_department.department_name);
    END;

    <<section_loop>>
    FOR r_section IN (
      SELECT 
        s.sections_id
      , s.sections_name
      FROM XMLTABLE (
      '/SECTIONS'
      PASSING r_department.sections
      COLUMNS
        sections_id   VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'SECTIONS_ID'
      , sections_name VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'SECTIONS_NAME'
      ) s
    )
    LOOP

      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO sections (id, name, department_id)
        VALUES (r_section.sections_id, r_section.sections_name, r_department.department_id);
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
          INSERT INTO section_duplicates (id, name, department_id)
          VALUES (r_section.sections_id, r_section.sections_name, r_department.department_id);
      END;

    END LOOP section_loop;

  END LOOP department_loop;

END;
/
```

This has the following benefits:

- You're able to trap the individual duplicates (if found) fairly easily, in terms of both departments and sections.
- You're not introducing cardinality due to program code - any duplicates are true input data duplicates.
- You don't have to worry about tracking the rows you're using / have used, it's implicit in the nested loop structure.